# How to find the last Children?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have following table in SQL server

```
    (id,name,parentId)
    (1,nilesh,NULL)
    (2,nikhil,1)    
    (3,nitin ,2)  
    (4,Ruchi,3)

    (5,xx,NULL)
    (6,YY,5)
    (7,ZZ,6)
```

I want to find the last child in each group

```
result: (4,Ruchi,3),(7,ZZ,6)
```

How to do it?

Comment: I didn't group it. It's clear if you follow the parent id of every record

Comment: Is another way to phrase it that you want to find rows whose value in column 1 (you haven't told us any column names) is not found in any rows' column 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable m
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    mytable mc
        WHERE   mc.parentId = m.id
        )
```

Checking:

```
WITH    mytable AS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    (
                VALUES
                (1,'nilesh',NULL),
                (2,'nikhil',1),   
                (3,'nitin' ,2),  
                (4,'Ruchi',3),
                (5,'xx',NULL),
                (6,'YY',5),
                (7,'ZZ',6)
                ) q (id, name, parentId)
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable m
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    mytable mc
        WHERE   mc.parentId = m.id
        )

---

4   Ruchi   3
7   ZZ  6
```

Comment: @RaymondMorphy: it does return what you asked for.